# Combine Multiple Tables Rows Into Master Table

Tags: excel, office-2013

Happy Monday Everyone!

Have a question and hope you can help. I have a budget spreadsheet that has a budget tab. On this tab is about 8 tables broken down into different categories. Every table in the tab has the exact same columns. Is there a non-vbscript/marco way to create a master table that combines all of the tables into a single table in a different tab. This seems like it would be a no brainer but I have tried everything I can think of and find online and there doesn't seem to be a decent solution without an addon called power query.

Comment: Yes at least two options. Pivottable from consolidated ranges. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46685803/combining-data-from-two-sheets-and-generating-pivot-table-in-another-sheet/46687935#46687935  or use Powerquery to combine tables into one and load to a new sheet as a master table http://www.contextures.com/excelpowerquerycombinetables.html

Comment: Go ahead and submit your pivot table answer as the answer and i'll make it. The only thing I was doing different from your guide is I didn't include the "[#All]" at the end of the table names, I just used the tables names and it didn't work.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "there doesn't seem to be a decent solution with an addon called power query." PowerQuery handles this easily, and is much better that the PivotTable from Consolidated Ranges approach. PowerQuery is now called "Get & Transform", and once you've used it a few times you'll be amazed at what you can do, just by muddling through.  It's also pretty simple to mash together data with VBA into a master table as well...especially if you turn all your data into Excel Tables as this make them very easy to reference with VBA. I'll post some code when I get a moment.

Comment: @jeffreyweir My Appologies, i meant to say *without* power query. But QHarr's solution worked.

Comment: Cool. Note that PivotTables created that way have significant limitations compared to using PowerQuery or VBA. Is there a particular reason why PQ and VBA are not your preference? Perhaps non technical, such as lack of knowledge? That used to hold me back on both counts, but this is a perfect learning opportunity to try multiple solutions, and to have your mind blown about what both can do, with no expertise needed your end.  I'm about to add another answer with some VBA code that is dead simple to trigger that does exactly what you want in milliseconds. But I've got to cook dinner first :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the functionality of the pivottable wizard to consolidate multiple ranges (which are your tables) together into one pivottable.

When it prompts for you to add your ranges use the table names with the following syntax: `Table4[#All]`

You need the [#All] to get all the data associated with the table. Just repeat this for each of your tables names you want to consolidate.

Full description i have given in my answer here:

[combining data from two sheets and generating pivot table in another sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46685803/combining-data-from-two-sheets-and-generating-pivot-table-in-another-sheet/46687935#46687935)

Note: If you want to keep the original table names or table numbers you will need to select the option:

1) "I will create the Page Fields"

2) Enter the Ranges using the table name e.g. Table4[#All]

3) Select how many page fields do you want 1-4 and add item label used to identify the selected ranges below e.g. Table4.

I am not sure if 4 items is the maximum or if this can be extended through VBA. However you can also use PowerQuery or UnionQuery.

The following quotes are from here: http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot08.html

I include some outline in case links are lost.

PowerQuery:

If you have a version of Excel that supports Microsoft's Power Query add-in, you can use it to combine the data in two or more tables. The tables can be in the same workbook, or in different files.

http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot08.html#videopowerquery

Union Query:

If you can't combine your data on a single worksheet, another solution is to create named ranges in an Excel file, and use Microsoft Query (MS Query) to combine the data.

http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot08.html#union01

Comment: This worked, Thank you! Only one small issue, in the filter dropdown menu it created an item called "page 1" that's in the filter field, and it has an entry for every table i referenced. Only issue is it labeled each of those items as 'item 1', 'item 2' etc instead of the table names. is there a way to rename those back to the table names instead of 'item #'

Comment: Can you simply alias them i.e. overwrite them in the pivottable with the desired names? I will have a look at other ways but often this can be done.

Comment: No because they are only visible in the filter dropdown field. Been searching but this seems to be a unique issue I'm having.

Comment: You can rename. I will update post. See here in interim: http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot08.html

Answer (score 4):

I know you asked for a non VBA way, but for completeness I'm adding another answer that also has a VBA solution, because it's dead simple, it's blazingly fast, and it's generic. All you need to do is cut and paste this code into a standard code module, add a button and assign it to trigger the calling routine, give your source tables a name includes the full name of the summary table, and you're good to go.

```
Sub CombineTables(loDest As ListObject, Optional lcSource As ListColumn)

Dim ws              As Worksheet
Dim lo              As ListObject
Dim lc              As ListColumn
Dim rDest           As Range
Dim lDestRows       As Long
Dim lSourceRows     As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If lcSource Is Nothing Then Set lcSource = loDest.ListColumns(1)
If loDest.ListRows.Count > 0 Then loDest.DataBodyRange.Delete

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each lo In ws.ListObjects
        If lo <> loDest Then
            With lo
                If InStr(.Name, loDest.Name & "_") > 0 Then
                    On Error Resume Next
                    lDestRows = loDest.ListRows.Count
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    lSourceRows = .ListRows.Count
                    If lSourceRows > 0 Then

                        'Work out where we want to paste the data to
                        Set rDest = loDest.HeaderRowRange.Offset(1 + lDestRows).Resize(lSourceRows)

                        'Resize the destination table
                        loDest.Resize loDest.Range.Resize(1 + lSourceRows + lDestRows)       

                        For Each lc In .ListColumns
                         Intersect(loDest.ListColumns(lc.Name).Range.EntireColumn, rDest).Value2 = lc.DataBodyRange.Value
                        Next lc
                        Set lc = Nothing
                        On Error Resume Next
                        Set lc = .ListColumns(lcSource.Name)
                        On Error GoTo 0
                        If lc Is Nothing Then Intersect(lcSource.Range, rDest.EntireRow).Value2 = ws.Name
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next lo
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

And here's the caller:

```
Sub CombineTables_Caller()
CombineTables [SomeName].ListObject, [SomeName].ListObject.ListColumns("Source")
End Sub
```

When I push that button, the code will look throughout the workbook for any tables who's names contain the name of the Destination table (in this case the Table called "SomeName"), and then bring their data through. So if you are adding new tabes, then as long as you prefix their Table names with the name of the destination table, they will be included. Any other tables (such as the one called 'DifferentName' will be ignored.

[image]

...and here's the result:

[image]

Comment: Whoops, found a small bug in the code that meant the last line was probably being omitted. Have amended.

Comment: Great stuff - very simple solution. However, did have one problem... comes up with a  Run-time error ‘9’ - Subscript out of range Error in the caller function. Any advice on why? I named my main consolidated tangle as ‘tblScore’ and all sub-tables in different tabs as ‘tblScorexx’ where xx is a number. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: What line is that coming up on?

Comment: Hi @jeffreyweir, sorry about the delay in responding.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Excel 2013 or later, then this is the perfect excuse to go play with PowerQuery, which is now called 'Get & Transform' in the ribbon. You can see something very similar to your requirement in my answer at [excel indirect function to read dates and return dynamic values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47164451/excel-indirect-function-to-read-dates-and-return-dynamic-values/47170312#47170312)

I strongly suggest you go and look at that thread...even if for some reason you can't use PowerQuery for this particular challenge, because I reckon it's worth seeing just how simple it is to mash together identical tables using PowerQuery, even if just for future reference. It's basically a VBA developer in a box. It's a VBA gimp!

Comment: This is used in a corporate environment and do not have the capacity to install addons.

Comment: What version of Excel is installed? Excel 2013 or later? If so, PowerQuery is baked in, and is launched from the "Get and Transform" ribbon. It is not a standalone addin, and IT couldn't turn it off if they tried. Also, VBA is not an addin either, and can be used in any version of Excel unless IT have completely disabled macros. (And I'm yet to work in a place where they have done this).

Comment: Hey downvoter: why stop with just *this* downvote? Why not go *anonymously* down-vote the other answer I freely gave also, without giving any feedback.