# Combine two non-contiguous ranges for pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If you have a table in excel all column headers are forced to be formatted as general text. I am trying to use a pivot table to reference the data in the table AND see the column headers as dates the only way to do this is to have a completely separate row somewhere else on the spreadsheet that's not part of the table but mirrors the columns with the exception of it being formatted as a date. Thus is my problem, I need to combine these two ranges to make a single range I can use as a value in the pivot table range.

```
OFFSET($B$11,0,0,ROWS(tblOther[#Data]),COLUMNS(tblOther[#Data]-2))
```

and

```
OFFSET(tblOther[#Data],0,0,ROWS(tblOther[#Data]),COLUMNS(tblOther[#Data]-2))
```

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use PowerQuery to accomplish that? Alternatively, you can setup an internal (self-referencing) ADO connection and then use SQL like so `SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM [SheetName$A1:C20] UNION ALL SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM [OtherSheetName$Z10:AB30] `.

Comment: Unfortunately PowerQuery is not an option.

Comment: And what about VBA?

Comment: Would like to avoid it if possible, but if not, its an option.

Comment: Okay. So at your other thread I've posted a pretty cool VBA routine I coded up earlier in the week to do just this very type of task. Doing this with formulas will be very icky by comparison, and will be a pain to maintain. It's late here now, but tomorrow I will add a couple of pics to your other post, in case you or others need help to implement the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Again, all I can do is point you to two great ways I suggested you can mash multiple tables together at your other thread at [Combine Multiple Tables Rows Into Master Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47277206/combine-multiple-tables-rows-into-master-table)

- One using PowerQuery, as Ralph suggests
- One using VBA.

Now I know at that other thread that you didn't want a PQ or VBA solution, but neither of them is that hard, and I've given you a link to a previous answer with step-by-step pictures that shows how easy PQ is, and a generic VBA routine that is pretty simple to implement.

If you want easy ways to mash tables together, then they are pretty much it. If there's some reason you can't use one or both of those, post back and let me know what the reason is and I'll see if I can help you overcome it.

Comment: Why the downvote? What is not useful about this answer?

Comment: You are well aware from my previous thread this is not an option for me.

Comment: At that thread you said "Is there a non-vbscript/marco way to create a master table". And you said  "There doesn't seem to be a decent solution without an addon called power query." Here I'm pointing out that a) PowerQuery is *not* an addin if you have 2013 or later, meaning it's just as native as say Formulas,  and b) you can use VBA such as the dead-simple-to-use plug and play routine I provided, which can be implemented  in *any* version of Excel. Your post above doesn't rule out PQ or VBA, and the other post rules them both out in a way that suggests you have incorrect information.

Comment: Downvoting two perfectly valid suggestions - one of which has been made by someone else - is just plain rude. Both answers are useful. Neither is ruled out by your requirements above. Both draw on my extensive knowledge of VBA/Excel development, something I have been doing for years, and have freely shared with you. I'm still going to go post photos at the other thread showing how to painlessly implement my VBA solution for completeness, but basically at this point I hope you don't bother looking at it, and use some other inferior result rather than take a second look at a first-rate solution.