# Excel: Create master list from worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have a need to create a master list in excel from various lists on other worksheets. The sizes, colors, other attributes will change so this will need to be done on occasion. The example data is:

Worksheet 1 "Products" contains:
Product Name
Product A
Product B
Product C
Product D

Worksheet 2 "Colors" contains:
Product Color
Red
Blue
Orange
Yellow
Green

Worksheet 3 "Sizes" contains:
Product Size
X-Small
Small
Medium
Large
X-Large

I need the completed list to look like:

•   Product A   Red X-Small

•   Product A   Red Small

•   Product A   Red Medium

•   Product A   Red Large

•   Product A   Red X-Large

•   Product A   Blue    X-Small

•   Product A   Blue    Small

•   Product A   Blue    Medium

•   Product A   Blue    Large

•   Product A   Blue    X-Large

•   Product A   Orange  X-Small

•   Product A   Orange  Small

•   Product A   Orange  Medium

•   Product A   Orange  Large

•   Product A   Orange  X-Large

•   Product A   Yellow  X-Small

•   Product A   Yellow  Small

•   Product A   Yellow  Medium

•   Product A   Yellow  Large

•   Product A   Yellow  X-Large

•   Product A   Green   X-Small

•   Product A   Green   Small

•   Product A   Green   Medium

•   Product A   Green   Large

•   Product A   Green   X-Large

•   Product B   Red X-Small

•   Product B   Red Small

•   Product B   Red Medium

•   Product B   Red Large

•   ...

•   Product D   Green   Medium

•   Product D   Green   Large

•   Product D   Green   X-Large

Is this possible? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Yes, it's possible, ya better get started!  :)  Stack Overflow isn't a "free spreadsheet design service" (although I'm starting to wonder where some people get that idea from)... If you want to learn to work with Excel do some searches on Google for Beginner's Excel Tutorials and take it from there.  What you're describing there is very-basic stuff, and is a great place to start.  Check out the [tour] as well as [how to ask] and [mcve].  If you have any _specific_ questions with an issue you tried to solve but can't, that's more what this site is for...

Comment: This is a very common question, you will find tens of this questions on Stack Overflow, just search and you will find very similar solutions

Comment: ok, sorry. I searched so I must have not done a very good job with the search. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

You can find two approaches from me at [Combine Multiple Tables Rows Into Master Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47277206/combine-multiple-tables-rows-into-master-table)

One of those uses VBA, the other uses PowerQuery (Excel 2010, 2013) aka "Get & Transform" (Excel 2016).