# Excel: Combine rows from multiple sheets that contain value

Tags: excel

I have several sheets that each contain an inventory list in a table. I would like to create a new sheet that combines all of the rows from all of the other sheets that contain a certain value in one of the columns. Ideally I would like the new sheet to contain only selected columns (which are columns that exist in all of the source sheets).

For example, **Sheet A** contains this table:

```
QTY  NAME              AUTHOR    PUBLISHER    COST
 1   The Blah Book     John      Kjos         14.00
 5   Another Book      Kate      Lewis        8.00
 3   Yet Another Book  Eric      Kjos         4.00
```

**Sheet B** contains this table:

```
QTY  NAME              PAGES     PUBLISHER    COST
 4   The Blah Document 15        Alfred       9.00
 6   Another Document  18        Kjos         15.00
 9   Yet Another Doc   12        Lewis        3.00
```

I'm looking for a way to create **Sheet C**, which would contain, for example, all the Kjos items, in selected columns that exist in all of the source sheets:

```
QTY  NAME              PUBLISHER    COST
 1   The Blah Book     Kjos         14.00
 3   Yet Another Book  Kjos         4.00
 6   Another Document  Kjos         15.00
```

I've tried a pivot table, which allowed me to combine multiple datasets but didn't seem to allow me to only gather rows that contained a search term, and a pivot table isn't exactly what I'm looking for.

I think I'm essentially looking for a formula similar to the `QUERY()` formula in Google Sheets... with multiple sources mixed together into one table.

Thanks for your help!

---

**BONUS:**

Even more ideally, I'd like duplicate entries to sum the quantity, so if Sheet B contained 3 of The Blah Book, then Sheet C would merge the two and list 4 of The Blah Book. But if that's reaching for the stars I can deal.

Comment: Actually, pivot tables sound like a good option here.  Just combine data sets.  After this, you may sort, filter, and aggregate the way you want.

Comment: Thanks. I'm open to a pivot table, but I couldn't figure out how to only include rows that contain the search term (publisher name). If that's possible could you please explain how?

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47277206/combine-multiple-tables-rows-into-master-table if any use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with powerquery and either filtering with/without a cell based parameter for PUBLISHER. It is a 2016 existing feature under Get & Transform in Data Tab; free add-in for 2013 Powerquery tab.

Sorry the images are so big.

---

### Step 1

If you are going with a parameter based query, picking up publisher name from a cell, then in cell A1 of a front sheet create a named range called `filterValue`. You can simply select A1 and type filterValue into the [Name](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64) box top left.

---

### Step 2

`Sheet A` Select a cell in table range and go to Data (or Powerquery tab) > From Table

[image: Data from table]

---

### Step 3

Make sure my table has headers is checked

[image: Headers]

---

### Step 4

Close and Load > Connection only (no need to select add to data model in this instance) > Load

[image: Close and load]

[image: Load to]

### Step 5

Repeat steps 1 to 3 for table 2 in `Sheet B`. Then select `Sheet C`.

---

### Step 6

Combine queries 1 and 2 by Data > New query > Combine Queries > Append

[image: Append queries]

---

### Step 7

Click Home > Advanced Editor and amend the top part of the script to look like as follows and then save:

```
filterParameter = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="filterValue"]}[Content],
filterParameterValue = filterParameter {0} [Column1],
Source = Table.Combine({Table1, Table2}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([PUBLISHER] =  filterParameterValue )),
```

This says, filter the column `PUBLISHER` on the value in the named range from step 1.

---

### Step 8

Remove unwanted columns with Select Columns `AUTHOR` and `PAGES` > Right click > Remove Column

[image: Remove columns]

---

### Step 9

Home > Group By > Advanced then use the settings below > Click ok

[image: Settings]

---

### Step 10

Add column > Custom Column and title it `TOTAL COST`

Add the formula `[COST]*[QTY]`

[image: Total Cost]

---

### Step 11

Select columns and drag to re-arrange if required. Perhaps rename Cost column as Unit Column by double-clicking on the column header.

[image: Column re-order and re-name]

---

### Step 12

Close and load to `Sheet C`  (existing worksheet)

[image: Close and load to sheet]

---

### Step 13

Observe result. Note I added in your bonus query so Sheet B has end row of:

```
3   The Blah Book   blank cell  Kjos    14
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]

---

**Reference:**

1. [Dynamic parameter values in queries](https://www.oraylis.de/blog/using-dynamic-parameter-values-in-power-query-queries)

---

**Full M code for CombinedTables**

```
let
    filterParameter = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="filterValue"]}[Content],
    filterParameterValue = filterParameter {0} [Column1],
    Source = Table.Combine({Table1, Table2}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([PUBLISHER] =  filterParameterValue )),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"AUTHOR", "PAGES"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"NAME", "PUBLISHER", "COST"}, {{"QTY", each List.Sum([QTY]), type number}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "TOTAL COST", each [COST]*[QTY]),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Custom",{"QTY", "NAME", "PUBLISHER", "COST", "TOTAL COST"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{{"COST", "UNIT COST"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Comment: This is awesome thanks, but I can't get it to show only the Kjos items. I have "Kjos" in cell C3, which I've named "filterValue" as you described, and my filter column is actually now called "DISTRIBUTING PUBLISHER", so I changed that in the code. What am I missing?

Comment: Hi. please reference against this https://ufile.io/e9oov Note that you must if you follow the steps above using the tables with the new name you should be fine. Just remember that adding the additional row to B you don't have a pages column so you leave that blank, and there isn't an Author column so you won't include that. I have edited the blank cell part into the answer.

Comment: Let me know how it goes

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It seems the issue is in the filterParameterValue but I'm not sure how. If I append the two tables and open the Power Query Editor, show the formula bar, and type `= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="filterValue"]}[Content]`, on yours it shows Column1 with "Kjos" underneath. On mine it shows "Kjos" as the header and then "This table is empty" underneath. I tried adding the cell above to the `filterValue` range, but then it showed Column1 with a blank cell and then Kjos underneath.

Comment: I followed your steps, but skipped step 3 - it didn't ask me for the table data range. I just clicked "From Table" and it immediately opened up the Power Query Editor. Could that be the issue? Is there a way I can indicate that the table has headers from the PQ editor?

Comment: Ahhh...you may need to add that named range as a separate table via query. I will have a look when I have more time tomorrow. Will rebuild from scratch and make sure I didn’t miss explaining anything.

Comment: You definitely need to ensure that there is a distinct header. That was called column 1 in my example.

Comment: Ah! I figured it out! When I changed the formula, I was only changing the `let` section, but the `in` section was still set as Source, from the original append. Might be worth editing the answer to make it easier for others to follow but thanks, I'll accept it!

Comment: Well done. Feel free to make the edit to my answer and I will review later today.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using excel 2013 and above, PowerQuery/Get and Transform is a way to go.
Pointing a query to excel file will append all the data contained, check this one:

[append queries](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/append-queries-power-query-e42ca582-4f62-4a43-b37f-99e2b2a4813a)