# Combining a master list (stacked) from a dynamic number of worksheets without spaces in between the data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a workbook that contains a dynamic number of worksheets, each labelled by an artists name and where each worksheet has a varying number of rows but the columns are all identical ( ref# | Name | Date Entered ).  Some of the worksheets might only have one or two rows, others 20 or 30.  I would like to combine a master list of all entries in all of the sheets on one master sheet.

I have used a simple SUM(FIRST:LAST!A2) formula in the past to get the value from a certain cell across all sheets between FIRST and LAST but that isn't doing the trick, I tried using the same range reference with VLOOKUP and COUNTIF.  I did find references to using Power Query, which I can use if I reference a specific sheet(s) but I can't figure out how to reference that dynamic range of worksheets when the sheet names change/new ones added/removed.  Also, I looked into Consolidate but again I wasn't able to figure out how to dynamically reference an unknown number of sheets so I figured some variation of the FIRST:LAST!A:A cell reference would be best.

Comment: A formula is not the way to go with this.  The best would be vba.

Comment: I did end up finding the appropriate VBA code online that works exactly as I hoped, on vbaexpress [link](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=151#instr) I just didn't have previous experience with that, but it works perfectly.

Comment: this article has given both approaches in **Power Query** and **VBA**. [combine-multiple-tables-rows-into-master-table/47278415#47278415](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47277206/combine-multiple-tables-rows-into-master-table/47278415#47278415). However please note the original question was asking to combine tables on one sheet but the logic would be the same if you give names to each table on each of your worksheet. Not sure how your worksheet is 'dynamic'. If the number of worksheet is changing from time to time, you may need to use a new workbook for the query.

Comment: Thanks, I did figure out some VBA code to get this result, and it wasn't that the worksheets were dynamic but the workbook itself as the number of worksheets that the master list pulls from is always changing.